# Push a Timeline Card to a given User ID

Tags: python, google-mirror-api

I'm playing with the Google Mirror API and I am struggling to find a way to push a card to a specific user only.

Given the userid ( 12345677 ) when I try to post the card with the following Python code:

```
 timeline_item = {'text': 'Test10'}
 timeline_item['recipients'] = [{'id':'12345677'}]
 self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=timeline_item).execute()
```

The card is visible in the timeline of all the other test users.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are coding in Python and using the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/). To push a timeline item to a specific user id, set the user id when creating the mirror service. The [Mirror API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/python) has an example of how to do this in its [notifications code](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/notify/handler.py#L41). The `recipients` field has nothing to do with to whose timeline the item gets pushed.

```
from oauth2client.appengine import StorageByKeyName
from model import Credentials

self.mirror_service = create_service(
        'mirror', 'v1',
        StorageByKeyName(Credentials, MY_USER_ID, 'credentials').get())
timeline_item = {'text': 'Test10'}
self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(body=timeline_item).execute()
```

Code for [`create_service`](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/util.py#L58)

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build

from model import Credentials

def create_service(service, version, creds=None):
  """Create a Google API service.

  Load an API service from a discovery document and authorize it with the
  provided credentials.

  Args:
    service: Service name (e.g 'mirror', 'oauth2').
    version: Service version (e.g 'v1').
    creds: Credentials used to authorize service.
  Returns:
    Authorized Google API service.
  """
  # Instantiate an Http instance
  http = httplib2.Http()

  if creds:
    # Authorize the Http instance with the passed credentials
    creds.authorize(http)

  return build(service, version, http=http)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `recipients` field doesn't specify who a timeline item should be sent to. It contains information about who has been sent the information on the card - it is intended for use by the REPLY_ALL card to be able to handle replies that should be sent to multiple people (not necessarily using Glass).

It isn't clear what language you're using, but it sounds like you are sending the item to all the authenticated users of your service.

Typically, you will specify the OAuth Token of a particular user to write to their timeline.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply. What i'm trying to achieve is to post the card to a specific user that logged into my glassware. What do you mean by specifying the OAuth Token ? Where in the payload sent to the mirror api should i use it?

Comment: You still haven't indicated what language you're using, so it is difficult to answer that question. But when the user logs in, you should be using the authentication token for all your communication with the mirror API. If you're looking at the raw HTTP, it would be through the Authorization header or the auth_token parameter.

Comment: Hi FaustoDassenno! It sounds like you actually have a slightly different question than the one you posted. Could you add another question asking how to post a card to a specific user that logged into your glassware? Keep this one too because it might be useful to other users in the future.